# What's the meaning of the dialogue "We will take them before last night's beer"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Please look at this picture.

[image: man in an old style bowler hat with a caption]

From "Peaky Blinders", Season 1 Episode 2

What does this dialogue mean?

> We will take them (talking about future) before last night's beer (something happened in past.)

Comment: I cannot see any picture

Comment: Peaky Blinders: *We will take them before last night's beer **turns to piss and wakes the devils up*** (before their bursting bladders wake them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full sentence is not shown.

The source is the Netflix series "Peaky Blinders", Season 1 Episode 2.

> "We will take them before last night's beer turns to piss."

This is a vulgar expression which means "**We will apprehend them quickly, today.**"

"take" here has the sense of t.v. 1a in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take :  **to seize or capture physically**

The meaning of the rest of the sentence should be obvious from the basic and universally understand facts of human metabolism:  if one drinks an excess of alcoholic liquid, micturation will occur within hours.